# I wanted to create an Uptime check for my API which is an internal TCP load balancer under VPC network?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I wanted to create an Uptime check for my API which is an internal TCP load balancer under VPC network . I have a firewall set-up and i have allowed the IP Address for US region to access this internal TCP load balancer . But I am getting the error "responded with Skipping Unsafe Address". I have provided the IP Address of my  internal TCP load balancer with port 8082 and protocol is HTTP and Resource Type is URL and I have given the value in path.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Stackdriver checks cannot check "non-routable" (also known as "private" IP addresses: (10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255, 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255). This is what accounts for the "Unsafe Address" error.

However, Private Checkers will be entering EAP soon, and you should be able to use them once they get to Beta. Private Checkers live on your VPC, and can probe non-routable addresses on your network.

Comment: What is your source for this information ? Are private checkers out in beta now ?

Comment: When I posted that comment, I was the Product Manager for Uptime. Private checkers are still on the roadmap, but we've encountered some issues that need to be resolved, and there will be some delay in getting this released to Beta. So right now, "RSN" is my current best estimate for availability.

Comment: @DanielKlein Any chance for an update, is this still aimed for?

Answer (score 2):

The capability is now (June 2021) in beta - If you are interested please contact us (or me directly)and ask to join the beta program.
The new capability allows you to run Private uptime checks - which means you can run your uptime checks on a private network.

Comment: Who would one need to contact to find out more about this beta program?

Comment: Hi @mcfedr - Please contact us here and I'll take it with you from there (let me know if you have issues) - https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1d9st7libQnIdju9T64JAGOpWJ1kqFmJ2-u2XfVVvISI/edit?ts=6079ffab&resourcekey=0-Cbg4F_wVep77Fx9h1ar-aw